# Probability for intersection of size $i$ between $k$ sets of size up to $N$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Assume that the elements in each set are sampled uniformly from $r$ possible elements ($N \le r$). It is also given that an element does not appear twice in a set.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "sampled uniformly?"  Your last sentence makes me believe "without replacement," but with a 'refreshed' population set of size $r$ for each sample set.

Comment: The setting is as follows. I am given $k$ sets of varying size. Say that each set $j=1,...,k$ is of size $S_j$, where $S_j \le N$. I know that the elements in each set are distinct. Moreover, the elements in each set can be chosen from a (constant) set of $r$ elements.